# How to write regex expression?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

**EDITED**

How to write regex that will check if string's length is 8 or more and it contains only digits then it should contain at least one alphabetical character. For example:

1. 1234567 - valid
2. 1234a5678 - valid
3. 12345678 - NOT valid because it's length is 8 and it doesn't contain any alphabetic

Comment: Your third example does not contain `more than 8 digits`. Therefore, according to your question, it should be valid.

Comment: i think he means if its less than 8 digits, it should contain only digits, more than or equal to 8 it should have at least one alphabetic character.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, I update my post. If it more than 7 digits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this `Regex`:

```
^(\d{0,7}|(\d*[a-zA-Z]\d*)+)$
```

and your code can like this:

```
var str = new List<string> {"1234567", "1234a5678", "12345678"};
foreach (string s in str)
{
    var isValid = Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^(\d{0,7}|(\d*[a-zA-Z]\d*)+)$");
}
```

Comment: This will catch `123x` for example. Less than 7 digits and a letter, which isn't what they want.

Comment: @Joey, that is exactly what I need. If it has up to 8(not including) only digits it's OK. Otherwise it has to contain at least one letter.

Comment: Yes, but the regex will match strings with *less* than 7 digits *and* a letter. I.e. it fails to do what you wanted. Unless I misunderstood your requirements.

Comment: @Joey, sorry if I mislead you. What I wanted is if string's length is  8 or more and it contains only digits, so it has to contain at least one alphabetic char.

Comment: Ok, now we have three different descriptions of your problem, all from you. Could you make up your mind, please?

Comment: @theateist: So the specification seems to be simply: if the string is less than 8 characters it's permitted to be all digits, otherwise it must contain at least one alpha character.  However, can there be more one alpha character? If so, I think this regex will fail.  If more than one alpha character is permitted, do they have to be in a run?  In other words, is `"1abc2"` valid? Is `"1a2b"`?

Answer (score 1):

Because the question changed my initial regex solution wouldn't work anymore. In fact, it's hard to do with a single regex now. So another option:

```
bool Validate(string s) {
    int numDigits = s.Count(c => char.IsNumber(c));
    if (numDigits <= 7) {
        return numDigits == s.Length;
    } else {
        int numLetters = s.Count(c => char.IsLetter(c));
        return numLetters > 0 && numDigits + numLetters == s.Length;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int Digits(string input) {
{
   int count = 0;
   foreach (char c in str)
   {
      if (c > '0' && c < '9')
          count++;
   }
   return count;
}

bool IsValid(string input)
{
    if (Digits(input) <= 8) {
        // is numeric
        return Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^[0-9]+$");
    }
    else {
        // has alpha && is alpha-numeric
        return Regex.IsMatch(input, @"[a-zA-Z]+") && Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$");
    }
}
```

Comment: @Joey Thank for pointing out my error. I've added start-of and end-of matchers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create & test your regex, don't hesitate to use this [regex.powertoy.org](http://regex.powertoy.org/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using c#, you can simplify your life and use two separate regex:

```
bool res = false;
string str = // your string
if (str < 8) 
{
    res = Regex.IsMatch(str, @"^[0-9]+$");
}
else 
{
    res = Regex.IsMatch(str, @"^(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]*$");
}
```